# How to use Windows API 'GetTcpTable' to find a avaiable tcp port?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to use windows api 'GetTcpTable', but I don't know how to prepare the data structure 'PMIB_TCPTABLE' and get the return value from it.

```
PROCEDURE GetTcpTable EXTERNAL "Iphlpapi":U:
   DEFINE OUTPUT        PARAMETER mTcpTable              AS HANDLE TO MEMPTR. // the API expects a pointer, so use HANDLE TO syntax to pass one
   DEFINE INPUT-OUTPUT  PARAMETER SizePointer            AS HANDLE TO LONG.
   DEFINE INPUT         PARAMETER Order                  AS LONG.
   DEFINE RETURN        PARAMETER IPHLPAPI_DLL_LINKAGE   AS LONG.
END PROCEDURE.
 
DEFINE VARIABLE mTcpTable        AS MEMPTR   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE SizePointer      AS INT      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE Order            AS INT      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE IPHLPAPI         AS INT      NO-UNDO.
 
DEFINE VARIABLE mTempValue       AS MEMPTR   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dwNumEntries     AS INT      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dwState          AS INT      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dwLocalAddr      AS INT64    NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dwLocalPort      AS INT      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dwRemoteAddr     AS INT64    NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dwRemotePort     AS INT      NO-UNDO.
 
DEFINE VARIABLE ix     AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
 
SizePointer = 4.
Order = 1.
SET-SIZE(mTcpTable) = SizePointer.
RUN GetTcpTable(OUTPUT mTcpTable, INPUT-OUTPUT SizePointer,INPUT Order, OUTPUT IPHLPAPI). //get ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER and know the real buffer now
 
MESSAGE "IPHLPAPI is " IPHLPAPI SKIP // ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122
        "SizePointer is " SizePointer SKIP
   VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
 
SET-SIZE(mTcpTable) = 0.
SET-SIZE(mTcpTable) = SizePointer.
RUN GetTcpTable(OUTPUT mTcpTable, INPUT-OUTPUT SizePointer,INPUT Order, OUTPUT IPHLPAPI). 
 
MESSAGE "IPHLPAPI is " IPHLPAPI SKIP  // NO_ERROR = 0
        "SizePointer is " SizePointer SKIP
        GET-LONG(mTcpTable,1) SKIP //dwNumEntries
   VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
 
IF IPHLPAPI = 0 THEN DO:
   dwNumEntries = GET-LONG(mTcpTable,1).
 
   OUTPUT TO VALUE ("C:\temp\debug.txt") UNBUFFERED.
   DO ix = 0 TO dwNumEntries - 1.
      dwState                 = GET-UNSIGNED-LONG(mTcpTable,5 + ix * 20). // get value of dwState
      dwLocalAddr             = GET-UNSIGNED-LONG(mTcpTable,9 + ix * 20). // get value of dwLocalAddr
 
      SET-SIZE(mTempValue)    = 2.
      PUT-BYTE(mTempValue,2)  = GET-UNSIGNED-SHORT(mTcpTable,13 + ix * 20).
      PUT-BYTE(mTempValue,1)  = GET-UNSIGNED-SHORT(mTcpTable,14 + ix * 20).
      dwLocalPort             = GET-UNSIGNED-SHORT(mTempValue,1). // get value of dwLocalPort, The maximum size of an IP port number is 16 bits, so only the lower 16 bits should be used. The upper 16 bits may contain uninitialized data.
      SET-SIZE(mTempValue)    = 0.
 
      dwRemoteAddr            = GET-UNSIGNED-LONG(mTcpTable,17 + ix * 20). // get value of dwRemoteAddr
 
      SET-SIZE(mTempValue)    = 2.
      PUT-BYTE(mTempValue,2)  = GET-UNSIGNED-SHORT(mTcpTable,21 + ix * 20).
      PUT-BYTE(mTempValue,1)  = GET-UNSIGNED-SHORT(mTcpTable,22 + ix * 20).
      dwRemotePort            = GET-UNSIGNED-SHORT(mTempValue,1). // get value of dwRemotePort, The maximum size of an IP port number is 16 bits, so only the lower 16 bits should be used. The upper 16 bits may contain uninitialized data.
      SET-SIZE(mTempValue)    = 0.
 
      PUT UNFORMATTED dwState "~t" dwLocalAddr "~t" dwLocalPort "~t" dwRemoteAddr "~t" dwRemotePort "~r".
   END.
   OUTPUT CLOSE.
END.
 
SET-SIZE(mTcpTable) = 0.
```

- Is there any better way to get the lower 16 bits? I'm not sure why I need to put the byte in a reversed order in to mTempValue, is it releated to little endian of x86 PC?
- How to get the right start position to read the value if I run the code on different bitness computer

I think the question can be closed now:
https://community.progress.com/s/feed/0D54Q000088eIeASAU?t=1602495359075&searchQuery
Thank you guys :)

Comment: You say that you are now attempting to use GetTcpTable.  But your code does not seem to show that. You should post the code that you are actually having a problem with.

Comment: Which line of your .Net example is throwing your error? On 11.6 and 12.2 (both x64) on Windows 10 I get either the port when the port is free, or port + 1 if the port is in use.

Comment: @TomBascom Thank you! Yes you are right, I shoud do this, but I had no idea with preparing the data structure when I was asking the question, so I didn't paste my code. Now I got the answer from the progress commnuity.
BTW: This is my first time ask question on stack overflow, what should I do next step? Should I paste the answer for this question or just close it?

Comment: You should at least upvote nwahmaet since you commented that his answer was worth a "Thanks".  Beyond that I would think that clarifying the original question to reflect what you were actually asking about, rather than showing code that is only tangentially related, would certainly be a good idea. Personally, I would then invite whoever answered your question on progress community to also post that answer here so that you can upvote it and mark it correct.

Comment: @TomBascom many appreciate for your suggestions, I have already edited my question and clarified what the actually question I'm asking about : )

Comment: @StefanDrissen Hi, thanks for your comments, I have edited my question to make it more clearer, I will update my previous quesiton via community.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's doc usually has the definitions of the structures (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tcpmib/ns-tcpmib-mib_tcptable). Once you know those - and any other that are related/pointed to/etc - you can create and manipulate them using `MEMPTR` data types and the various functions that operate on them: `SET-SIZE()`, `GET-BYTES()` and `GET-POINTER-VALUE()` are typically used. There is doc on this at https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-programmimg-interfaces/page/Shared-Library-and-DLL-Support.html .

Comment: Hi Thanks,  

I can retrieve the informations from the return value now.   

But my start position of MIB_TCPROW table[ANY_SIZE] is the 5th byte of mTcpTable, it looks like that the bytes value in mTcpTable is followed theis order: dwNumberEntries, MIB_TCPROW table[1], MIB_TCPROW table[1]... is it right?  

Sorry I don't know how to paste the code because of the limit of comment characters